# tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("All Calculators"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("My Calculators"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

//        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#71CDF5"));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
//does not change the tab's title color when selected
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#71CDF5"));
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a workaround for this issue.
In styles.xml i added the following code.

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextStyle</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#71CDF5</item>
        <!--<item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/primaryDark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

and then in my tab layout i added the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3B4245"
    style="@style/AppTheme.TabStyle"
    android:elevation="6dp">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

and it was done. I did remove the following code from the main class

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#71CDF5"));
```

there maybe better way to solve this problem, i am not sure this is the exact way to achieve this.

Comment: for me it works when selecting a tab through UI (taping on a tab) but calling viewPager.setCurrentItem(...) moves the indicator but does not update the text color. I'm using design library 23.1.0. I wonder if it's a bug in the library

Comment: @jfcartier I did not try tapping on UI but if it is a bug on library many people would have faced the same issue, but that does not seems the case here. If you do find out please share your knowledge :)

Comment: I am also facing same issue as @jfcartier mentioned. viewPager.setCurrentItem() does not change Tab indicator color but not the text color. I am also using support library. Anyone have found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying the same and finally come with a solution. I tried all and finally i tried the below solution and it worked charm for me.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The ViewPager2 version of this is viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback, and then you can override the same 3 methods onPageScrolled, onPageSelected, and onPageScrollStateChanged.